# Angular2 select with ngModel is empty (template driven)

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a select with options filled by an array. Unfortunately nothing is selected even when the first option has the attribute `selected`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <select name="fruits" [ngModel] required>
      <option *ngFor="let fruit of selectData;" [ngValue]="fruit">{{fruit}}</option>
    </select>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectData = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Kiwi'];
}
```

Even worse: If i add the selected attribute to the first element by `[attr.selected]="i == 0"` the select is valid (it is required) but still shows no selected value. Could this be a bug maybe?

Answer (score 0):

**Example with your code**

This is very easy with template driven forms. But gives you less control over validation.

```
<select name="fruits" [ngModel] required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
      <option *ngFor="let fruit of selectData;" [ngValue]="fruit">{{fruit}}</option>
    </select>
```

**Template Driven Example**

```
 <select class="form-control" id="state" required [(ngModel)]="address.state" name="state" #state="ngModel">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
<option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</option>
 </select>
```

**Model Driven Example**

This is a model driven example. You have more control over your forms with model driven forms but this specific task you are trying to complete is simple. with template driven I believe all you need to do is add a placeholder.

Here is how I handle adding states to the combobox,

*In the component.html file,*

```
<select (blur)="stateValidate('State *Required', 'State Name')"          
    class="form-control" id="state_address" formControlName="state_address">
    <option *ngFor="let state of states">{{state}}</option>
</select>
```

*In the component.ts file,*

```
states = ['Select State', 'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Federated States of Micronesia', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Island', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
```

**Explanation**

Notice the first value is `Select State`. In my case this does not validate unless the user changes it to an actual state.

That being said if a user does change it to a state and then back to 'Select State' it does validate and allow the form to be submitted.

Please notice in this image the State field is `red` for not valid and the form `Update` `button` is inactive because all the fields in the form are not valid.

[image]

**The Blur Function I Add**

I take my validation a step further and add a blur function. This way when the user leaves the input field I can immediately check to see if they entered something acceptable or not. Just to give you an idea of what that looks like here is the blur function that gets called when you leave the `combobox` for state selection.

```
stateValidate(ErrorTitle, ErrorMessage) {
        if (this.profileForm.get('state_address').status == VALID) {
            this.toastSuccess("State Entered", "State entered correctly");
        } else {
            this.toastWarning(ErrorTitle, ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

If this input field is not valid then a toast will appear directing the user to fill it out correctly. You could use this same methodology to check the value of the input field and make sure it is not the `Select State` in my case.

Comment: Hey I updated my code. Check the first example using your code. If you are using Template driven forms you should be able to just add an option and make it disabled. You can see the second example is using my code from when I used template driven forms for state selection in a combo box. Then the third example is for model driven forms. But there would be a lot more work to get model driven to work.

Comment: Even i dont want a "Select your option" default value I tried your example, but still the select is empty.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around for this could be (rather ugly though)

```
<select name="fruits" [(ngModel)]="fruit" required>
  <option *ngFor="let fruit of selectData;" [ngValue]="fruit">{{fruit}}</option>
</select>
```

and in your component you could give it a default value:

```
this.fruit = this.selectData[0];
```